# Compare two predicates in Prolog

Tags: prolog

First of all, thank you for your help.
I'm studying Prolog right now, and I found a problem.

It might be a stupid problem, but I still not figure it out.

In Prolog,

```
go(1) = go(1)
```

will return true.

```
go(1) = go(2)
```

will return false.

But when I try

```
not(go(1) = go(2))
```

it also returns false as follow

```
[trace]  ?- not(go(1) = go(2)).
Call: (8) not(go(1)=go(2)) ? creep
Fail: (8) not(go(1)=go(2)) ? creep
false.
```

Could anyone help me explain it please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can not reproduce this, locally `not(go(1) = go(2))` results in `true`.

Comment: Same here. When I try `not(go(1) = go(2)).` in SWI Prolog I get "true" as expected. What Prolog implementation are you using and what version?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried using `go(1) \= go(2)` and it returned true.. So confusing. Still have no idea why not `not(go(1) = go(2))` work. Is there any difference between `\=` and `not` ?

Comment: @lurker I'm using SWI Prolog version 7.7.19

Comment: What if you do `\+ (go(1) = go(2))`? (Note `(\+)/1` is the ISO standard predicate for "not provable", whereas `not/1` is the non-standard version).

Comment: @lurker it returned true in this way. Thanks for you help. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I think 7.7.19 is later than the latest "stable" version (7.6.4), so be aware you're living on the edge... ;)

Comment: @lurker Okay, thanks again, I'll be aware :).

Comment: I just pulled, built, and tried version 7.7.22-74-g0211f0ce6 and it behaves as expected: `\+ (go(1) = go(2))` and `not(go(1) = go(2))` succeed (responds with "true"). Try pulling the latest version and rebuild. Perhaps there was a temporary bug in the build.